# Emacs tramp causes stack overflow

Tags: emacs, elisp, tramp

I am using emacs version 24.4.2. For some reason, i cannot use tramp at all. Any attempt to do so, i.e. trying to type `/sudo::` causes a small hang of application followed by the following error in messages buffer:

```
expand-file-name: Lisp nesting exceeds `max-lisp-eval-depth'
```

What can i do to fix that error or diagnose it properly?

Update: Debugging shows the source of a problem is `ido`. Currently it is set up with following:

```
  (setq ido-everywhere t)
  (ido-mode t)
  (setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `debug-on-error` to non-`nil`. See what function called `expand-file-name`, producing the error. Then try `M-x debug-on-entry F`, where `F` is that function, and step through the debugger with `d` to see what happens. Look at the code defining that function, in another window, while using the debugger.

You can also try, first, seeing whether you get the same broken behavior when you start Emacs without your init file: `emacs -Q`. If not, then recursively bisect your init file to find out what part of it introduces the problem.

My crystal ball is whispering to me that you have advised a function in such a way that it ends up, directly or indirectly, calling itself.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. You are right on several accounts: launching without init files results in correct behaviour of tramp. Debugging leads to `ido-find-file`, which, as far as i can tell, is shadowing `find-file`. That's something i can work out, i think. But any advice on how to set ido to work with tramp will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, someone else will have to help with that. I don't use Ido. ;-)